# Expandable list checkboxes disappear after collapse all

Tags: javascript, list, checkbox, expandable

I have a form in a javascript expandable list. In several of the headers I have checkboxes and radio buttons. I also have an expand all and collapse all button. My problem is, after clicking the collapse all button, if I click on a list item the checkbox doesn't show up. If I click on expand all button everything shows up normally, but then I have to click on the headers to collapse them down again. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bHk2r/2/) that reproduces the problem.

Edit to clarify: The problem only occurs after clicking on collapse all, and then clicking on the list header. The child headers no longer show the checkboxes.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="listContainer">
        <div class="listControl">
            <a id="expandList">Expand All</a>
            <a id="collapseList">Collapse All</a>
        </div>
        <form id="ColForm" action="Table.php" method="post"> <!--Organized list of collumns and filter options-->
        <ul id="expList">
        <li>Section heading
            <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="ColSelect" value="Name" form="ColForm"> <!--If checked, collumn will be included in final table--> Name
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="text" name="Name" form="ColForm"><br> <!--filter parameter input-->
                </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="ColSelect" value="RA,Dec" form="ColForm">Another collumn
                <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="radio" name="PoSearch" value="Range" form="ColForm">Radio button to select form type for this section<br>
                    <i>I have an option here
                    <input type="radio" name="Degs" value="Dec" form="ColForm">Option 1 
                    <input type="radio" name="Degs" value="Hex" form="ColForm">Option 2</i><br>
                    Text input 1<br>
                    <input type="text" name="RA" form="ColForm">deg<br>
                    Text input 2<br>
                    <input type="text" name="Dec" form="ColForm">deg<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="PoSearch" value="Area" form="ColForm">Second form option<br>
                    <i>Text input A</i><br>
                    <input type="text" name="Area" form="ColForm"><br>
                </li>
                </ul>    
            </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" form="ColForm">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#expList ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expList p {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
    background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Collapsed state for list element */
#expList .collapsed {

}
/* Expanded state for list element
/* NOTE: This class must be located UNDER the collapsed one */
#expList .expanded {

}
#expList {
    clear: both;
}


.listControl{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.listControl a {
    border: 1px solid #555555;
    color: #555555;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
}
.listControl a:hover {
    background-color:#555555;
    color:#222222; 
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function prepareList() {
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        //return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();

    //Create the button functionality
    $('#expandList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().show('medium');
    })
    $('#collapseList')
    .unbind('click')
    .click( function() {
        $('.collapsed').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.collapsed').children().hide('medium');
    }) 
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    prepareList()
});
```

Comment: for me it's working good. no problem detected.

Comment: Did you expand the list manually after clicking "collapse all"? It works fine otherwise, that's the only place the problem occurs.